# how to secure a route for authenticated user only Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have created few routes in my application as

```
  scope "/", Socialistical do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack


    get "/", UserController, :index
    get "/sign_up", UserController, :sign_up
    post "/create_user", UserController, :create
    options "/create_user", UserController, :nothing

    post "/session", SessionController, :create
    delete "/logout", SessionController, :delete

    get "/dashboard", DashboardController, :index
  end
```

As other routes than dashboard are those which could be available to the public. But I want to secure dashboard route for authenticated user only. I have created a session model as

```
defmodule Socialistical.Session do
  alias Socialistical.User

  def current_user(conn) do
    id = Plug.Conn.get_session(conn, :current_user)
    if id, do: Socialistical.Repo.get(User, id)
  end

  def logged_in?(conn), do: !!current_user(conn)
end
```

I want to utilise these 2 methods for securing all coming routes which will be available for the authentic user only, Please help me in this. I am kind unaware how could  I make/convert it to plug.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example. This examples only handles verifying a logged in user. It does not handle redirecting to a login page.

Here is the plug

```
defmodule Socialistical.Session do
  @behaviour Plug
  import Plug.Conn
  alias Socialistical.Accounts.User
  alias Socialistical.Repo

  def current_user(conn), do: conn.assigns[:current_user]
  def logged_in?(conn), do: !!current_user(conn)

  def init(opts \\ []) do
    # simple example to show how options can be passed
    %{error: opts[:error] || "Not authorized"}
  end

  def call(conn, opts \\ []) do
    if user = get_user(conn) do
      # we have a session so store it for latter access
      assign conn, :current_user, user
    else
      # not session
      halt_with_error conn, opts[:error]
    end
  end

  defp halt_with_error(conn, error) do
    conn
    |> send_resp(401, error)
    |> halt
  end

  defp get_user(conn) do
    case Plug.Conn.get_session(conn, "current_user") do
      nil -> nil
      id -> Repo.get(User, id)
    end
  end
end
```

And the router:

```
defmodule Socialistical.Web.Router do
  use Socialistical.Web, :router
  # ...
  pipeline :protected do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
    plug Socialistical.Session
  end

  scope "/", Socialistical.Web do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    get "/login/:id", PageController, :login

    # just here for the example
    resources "/users", UserController
  end

  scope "/", Socialistical.Web do
    pipe_through :protected
    get "/protected", PageController, :protected
  end
end
```

Here is a controller for testing. I added a login action just to test it all worked. Its only for demo purposes since it does not authenticate the user, only creates the session.

```
defmodule Socialistical.Web.PageController do
  use Socialistical.Web, :controller
  alias Socialistical.Accounts

  def index(conn, _params) do
    render conn, "index.html"
  end

  def protected(conn, _params) do
    render conn, "protected.html"
  end

  def login(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    user = Accounts.get_user!(id)
    conn
    |> put_session("current_user", user.id)
    |> assign(:current_user, user)
    |> redirect(to: "/")
  end
end
```

I tested this and it should all work. You should review the [Plug docs](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/readme.html#hello-world). As well, you can look at my authentication package [Coherence Session plug](https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence/blob/master/lib/coherence/plugs/authorization/session.ex) to get some more ideas.